# Controlling Arduino from Raspberry Pi

Tags: programming, pins, arduino-leonardo

I am trying to control an Arduino Leonardo R3 to run some code when "triggered" from a Raspberry Pi. This would be in a loop so that it can be run multiple times. I have set up the Raspberry Pi and tested it with an LED and the output is working fine.

I then connected this to the Arduino and checked for a HIGH input from the RPi using an if statement.

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(7,INPUT);
  if(digitalRead(7)==HIGH) {
    // CODE IN HERE
  }
}
```

I found that this did not work as the if statement was always true because of pullup resistors not being used. I would greatly appreciate some guidance on this.

Comment: `setup()` runs only once, when the board is switched on (or reset). You should test pin 7 in `loop()` instead.

Comment: How do you connect the Arduino with RPi?

Comment: The reason I put it in setup first was because if I did something wrong didnt want it to continue constantly.

I connected the GPIO from the RPi direct to the Arduino pin 7.

Comment: Be careful connecting the Raspberry Pi to the arduino directly. The 5V signals on the Arduino can damage the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: The Arduino is being used as an input, will this be OK?

Comment: I don't know for sure. But a bug in your arduino code that sets the the input pin as an output would be a problem.

Comment: Should you change setup (Arduino + RPi), consider an Arduino Yun: it's a Leonardo and a Linux box on one board

Comment: possible duplicate of [Controlling Arduino from Raspberry Pi](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/6635/controlling-arduino-from-raspberry-pi)

Comment: What I am basically trying to do is, program Java on a PC to control the RPi GPIO which controls the Arduino to run some code. The reason I chose the RPi was because I had one and thought it would be a simple "read input" setup but if there is any other way of doing this then please let me know.

Comment: Just thought, what if the if statement was for a key event and Java ran this keydown event, would this work?

Comment: Voting to close this as unanswerable, since two years have passed without the necessary information ever being provided.  As pointed out in the very first comment, the posted code only runs once, hence it cannot determine what is "always" the state of the input as claimed.  Without any information about what aspect of the code's behavior is being observed and *without any code that would generate observable output included in the question*, this is unanswerable.

Answer (score 2):

You have to verify, at least:

A. if the 3.3V of the RPi can be read as high on the Atmega, if so you can connect them without any resistor.

B. if not, you have to use a voltage adapter (yes, other components and many possible solutions), otherwise you RPi GPIO will be ruined if using a pullup on the 5V.

The pullup and pulldown, in this case, should be used when you are in A and the peripheral support the higher voltage. This is not the case.

Comment: No adapter or pullup is needed - an ATmega at 5v actually has a lower threshold for a "1" than the pi's 3.3v CPU does.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience about Arduino boards connected to the Pi, never tried anything other than Arduino Due, but I do have some experiences with ATmega328P directly attached to the Pi. The ATmega is clocked at 12MHz instead of 16 to guarantee a stable state at 3.3V supply voltage.

Physical connection takes 5 signal wires besides the 3.3V power rail, with the ATmega talking with the Pi over SPI as a slave device, using both slave select lines, one at the SS pin and the other at RESET pin. This allows communication over proper hardware interfaces while eliminates the need of a programmer or preprogrammed chips as the ATmega use its SPI interface as ICSP, this setup essentially keep ICSP properly wired to the Pi at all times. An additional pin can be used as a IRQ pin from the ATmega to the Pi.

About the protocol that part is up to yourself. There are endless possibilities and you can implement anything that fits your need and easy to use.

Comment: That's possible, yes, but seems a lot more than what the poster is trying to achieve.  USB current limits on various pi models aside, one can also plug the Arduino into the pi's USB instead of a PC's.

Comment: I have built myself a Arduino-like shield for Pi based on this idea. And it uses fresh chips, no bootloader required.

Comment: That's nice, but a lot more work and not really what the poster seems to be trying to do at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this in a different manner.

I have used the UART TX pin of RPi connected to the RX pin of the arduino and sent serial messages from Arduino to RPi.

That worked fine.

But the thing is, what you have done is correct and has to work.

Please make sure that you have connected Arduino's ground and RPi ground together.

---

If you not do that and try the same code it has to work. Because the RPi and Arduino are in two different circuits, so in order to work, make them one make GROUND common.