# Controlling Arduino from Raspberry Pi

Tags: programming

I am trying to simply send a digital output from the Raspberry Pi to trigger some code on an Arduino. I have setup the Pi with the digital output working fine (tested using LED) however, I cant seem to get the Arduino (Leonardo) to read this output. I mean, all the details about the Pull Up resistor and logic having to be low to be high is confusing me and I really dont want to use any other electronic components (ie transistors or switches, etc).

Is there a simple way of just reading the output and triggering the code on the Arduino?